# Generate widgets automatically for a generic layer's fields attributes in a custom feature form in QGIS

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

I'm trying to create a custom attribute form in QGIS useful to modify the current layer. I have already created a custom interface in Qt-Designer with QLabels and QLineEdits. In particular, a generic QLineEdit is used to show the attribute of layer's feature and to achieve this I know that the objectName of a QLineEdit istance must have the same name as the field whose attribute I want to show. Like showed in the picture below. Until now no problem.

[image: Example of QLineEdit objectName in Qt-Designer]

My goal is to create a custom attribute form usable with more than a specific layer so I need to generate automatically, from python code, the instances of QLineEdit class, each with specific objectName based on fields' name I want to show. I'm able to add custom widgets to the myDialog object, each named as the field I want to show, but QGIS seems not recognize the object and doesn't put the attributes inside the generic QLineEdit instance.

With these lines of code

```
...

def formOpen(dialog,layerid,featureid):
    
    global myDialog
    myDialog = dialog
    global nameField

    main_layer = myDialog.layer()
    main_feature = myDialog.feature()
    
    # get useful widgets
    title_main_layer = myDialog.findChild(QLabel, "title_main_layer")
    title_target_layer = myDialog.findChild(QLabel,"title_target_layer")
    ok_button = dialog.findChild(QPushButton,"ok_button")   
    frame_main_layer = myDialog.findChild(QFrame, "frame_main_layer")
    # set the layout of this frame
    layout = QGridLayout(frame_main_layer)
    
    # get the list of layer's fields
    fields = [field.name() for field in main_layer.fields()]
    # add QLabels and QLineEdits inside frame
    for row, field_name in enumerate(fields):
        # label as illustrative scope
        label = QLabel(field_name)
        # lineedit to show the attribute of field
        lineedit = QLineEdit()
        lineedit.setObjectName(field_name)
        # add widgets to layout
        layout.addWidget(label,row,1)
        layout.addWidget(lineedit,row,2)
    
    ...
```

and I get this result on QGIS

[image]

where the frame highlighted in cyan is the `frame_main_layer` where I added the label and lineedit. Within the bottom frame the result I want to get. Any suggestions?

Comment: You may get more interest in this question over at [gis.se].

Comment: Thanks @larsks! I will try and hope for some help.